# Flask Admin and SQLAlchemy relationship advice, how do I get columns from a grandparent table?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Using Flask Admin, I'm having difficulties understanding how to retrieve columns from parent and grandparent tables to use for filtering / create dropdowns

```
class Project(db.Model):

    project_id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title=db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def get_id(self):
        return self.project_id

class Story(db.Model):

    story_id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description=db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    project_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Project.project_id))
    project=db.relationship(Project)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.description

    def __str__(self):
       return self.description

    def get_id(self):
        return self.story_id

class Task(db.Model):

    task_id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description=db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    story_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Story.story_id))
    story=db.relationship(Story)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.description

    def __str__(self):
       return self.description

    def get_id(self):
        return self.task_id

class TaskModelView(ModelView):

    create_modal = False
    edit_modal = False
    can_set_page_size = True
    page_size = 20
    column_display_pk = True
    column_display_all_relations = True

admin.add_view(TaskModelView(Task, db.session))
```

When dealing with the Tasks list, I see the Story description with no problems and can use that to filter the list but how would I obtain the Project title and be able to filter on that column?

Have been searching the docs but obviously missing something ..

Comment: You have established relationships from the child ("many" side) to the parent ("one" side), but not in the other direction. See the [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
class TaskModelView(ModelView):
    ...
    column_list = [ 'description', 'story', ]
    column_filters = ['description', 'story.description', ]
    column_labels = {'story.description': 'Story Desc.'}
```

References [here](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/).